# Reportings services + drop down list length + different user'r rights

Tags: reporting-services, drop-down-menu

I have some report and plenty of parameters inside that report. One of parameter contains values stored inside dropdown list (that are downloaded from db). I wanted to set the custom width for a specific drop down list in my report so I do it by adding the following code in Report.aspx file located in: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.XX\Reporting Services\ReportManager\Pages:

```
<style type="text/css">
#ctl140_txtValue
{
width:350px;
}
</style>
```

and this works fine when I run my report in Reporting Services as administrator. But however when I attempt to run report as a normal user then the drop down list has a normal width (not changed to be 350px). Can someone please help me.

**PROBLEM HAS BEEN FOUND AND FIXED!**
I figured out that when normal user (without administrative) rights opened reporting services report, then less controls were generator and control with id ctl140_txtValue has in fact the following id ctl139_txtValue

Comment: when you have resolved your own question, you can enter it as an answer to the question, then (after a certain period, I think) accept it as the answer.

Comment: Thank you Mark for an information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM HAS BEEN FOUND AND FIXED!**
I figured out that when normal user (without administrative) rights opened reporting services report, then less controls were generator and control with id ctl140_txtValue has in fact the following id ctl139_txtValue